# Is there a way to ignore the whole line if one value in line is null(i.e., 5,fee,) values present in file

Tags: java

File format

```
person_number,name,age
1,Ram,24
5,fee, 
2,sam,20
3,Test,24
4,sample,25
```

code

```java
while (((line = br.readLine()) != null)) { 
    String[] employeeDetails = line.split(COMMA_DELIMITER);
    
    if ((employeeDetails.length > 0)) {
       try {

            ADInputFile emp = new ADInputFile(employeeDetails[0], employeeDetails[1],
                    employeeDetails[2]);
            empList.add(emp);
            

        }
```

Comment: I am *guessing* that you may be looking for `line.split(COMMA_DELIMITER, -1);`. But you need to [edit] your question and clarify what is *currently happening* vs what you *want* to happen instead.

Comment: Ignore how? The whole line or?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Yes, i wan to ignore whole line (i.e. 5,fee,)

Answer (score 1):

Access `employeeDetails[2]` only when `employeeDetails.length >= 3`; otherwise, you will get `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`. This will also ensure to ignore the records which do not have values for all the three fields e.g. `record#2` in your question.

```
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
    String[] employeeDetails = line.split(COMMA_DELIMITER); 
    if (employeeDetails.length >= 3) {
       try {
            ADInputFile emp = new ADInputFile(employeeDetails[0], employeeDetails[1],
                    employeeDetails[2]);
            empList.add(emp);
        } catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

**Note:** If a line has more than three values, it will pick the first three values. In case you want to ignore also those lines which have more than three values, use the condition, `employeeDetails.length == 3` instead of `employeeDetails.length >= 3`.

Comment: Well then at least fix the compilation error

Comment: @JoakimDanielson - Thanks for the feedback. I copied-pasted the code from the question and focussed mainly on solving the problem. There was an unnecessary additional pair of parentheses for each of, `while` and `if` conditions. Also, the `catch` block was missing which I've corrected.